# What are the possible causes for DataBindingUtil.setContentView to return null occasionally?

Tags: android-databinding

The following code works perfectly at least 99.9% of the time:

```
FooBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.foo);
```

Occasionally, binding is null.

Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of this?   I want to give a helpful message to the user when this occurs.